# How to deserialize/serialize struct as array without keys

Tags: json, rust, serde, cbor

How can I de/serialize struct without keys ? Since i will not be changing the order of fields, Indexes can act as keys which will reduce the size of payload.

I'm working with serde_json and ciborium crates which both have top level array value.

for example,

following cbor/json

```json
["string1", 1, 1.1, [4, 34, 4, 4]]
```

should be converted into this

```rust
struct Foo {
    a: String,
    b: u128,
    c: f64,
    d: Vec<u8>,
}
```

I could manually do this by using [Value::array](https://docs.rs/ciborium/0.1.0/ciborium/value/enum.Value.html#variant.Array) enum of ciborium crate but then I will end up writing more code and won't be able to use `serde_bytes` crate to efficiently decode `Vec<u8>`

Comment: You can write your own `impl` of `Deserialize` for `S1`: https://serde.rs/impl-deserialize.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use [`serde_tuple`](https://crates.io/crates/serde_tuple) that is dedicated to "De/serialize struct as an array of values" issue [#637](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/issues/637):

```rust
#[derive(serde_tuple::Serialize_tuple, serde_tuple::Deserialize_tuple)]
struct Foo {
    a: String,
    b: u128,
    c: f64,
    d: Vec<u8>,
}
```